# Adding Background image to EJS file

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I seem to be fine getting an image to render from my app.js file to the main ejs file, but when i change it to a background image, it does not display. Any idea whats up?

**my app.js**

```
const express = require("express"),
  app     = express(),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  jade = require("jade"),
  path = require('path'),
  redis = require('redis');
  images = [{image:"http://nuvotera.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/email-protection-banner-2.jpg"}];

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//render email page
app.get("/email", function(req, res){
  res.render("emailMain", {image:images});
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Email Server has started");
});
```

from the ejs page

```
<tr>
<% for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++){ %>

  <td class="vmlHero" background = "<%= images.image %>" style="background-repeat:no-repeat" bgcolor="#000000" width="100%" height="430" valign="top">
```

Comment: `res.render("emailMain", {image:images});`  did you mean `res.render("emailMain", {images:images});`

Answer (score 1):

I solved as this  easiest solution.

ejs file

add this in your css file

```
body {
        width: 100%;
        align-items : center;
        height: 100%;
         

        /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
        background-position: center center;

        /* Background image doesn't tile */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
        the content's height is greater than the image's height */
        background-attachment: fixed;

        /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
        on the container's size */
        background-size: cover;

        /* Set a background color that will be displayed
        while the background image is loading */
        background-color: green;
        overflow: hidden;

        /* Location of the image */
        background-image:url('images/introBackGround.jpg') ;
    }
```

(remove all blockquotes)

router file

you must add this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

folder

```
public
 └ images
  L css
```

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same thing and this worked for me:

```
<div class="containerImage" style="background-image: url('<%= img%>')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
app.get("/email", function(req, res){
  res.render("emailMain", {image:images});
});
```

should be this:

```
app.get("/email", function(req, res){
  res.render("emailMain", {images: images});
});
```

Note the extra `s`.

Also, you aren't using the variable `i` here:

```
<tr>
<% for(var i=0; i < images.length; i++){ %>

  <td class="vmlHero" background = "<%= images.image %>" style="background-repeat:no-repeat" bgcolor="#000000" width="100%" height="430" valign="top">
```

I think that should be `<%= images[i].image %>`, or just use a `forEach` instead.

It's also worth noting that the `background` attribute of `td` is deprecated, you could achieve the same effect using a `background-image` or `background` in the style.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js change

```
res.render("emailMain", {image:images});
```

To:

```
res.render("emailMain", {images:images});
```

And in your .ejs file change

```
background="<%= images.image %>"
```

To:

```
background="<%= images[i].image %>"
```