# adding a background image with a local file

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a .ejs file in a folder of various ejs files (representing pages) that has the code:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('a.jpeg');
    }
</style>
```

I have an image called a.jpeg in the same directory, but when I load the page, nothing appears and in the console I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. What is the correct way to set the background image as a local file?

Comment: Hi, please can you provide the html? if you are including  your ejs like a template footer, for example, it could be that your file is in another location. 
That is why you have that message.

Comment: maybe this can help :https://stackoverflow.com/q/46573549/12348877

Comment: How is the ejs being compiled?

Comment: What do you mean by _local_ file? Clearly `a.jpeg` doesn't exist (or is not accessible due to permissions or a server setting) in the same location as the web page (or it's base address if a `<base>` tag is present). You posted so little code with so little detail!

Comment: @Roberto you were right, the location for the file was actually different. Thanks.